# Find a string in 8000 Ms word files

Tags: c#, filestream

I stored many word file in my SQL database using FileStream , now I want to search in all of them to return those witch contains a string.

The first solution that I found is open each file and read content of them and search for given string (Using File stream)

The second solution is to do not use FileStream and store the content of word in database, so this cause to we need a big big hard space!!!

Is there any one to help me about this !?

***UPDATE1** : I am creating a Document Management System in WPF. This application will work on a LAN. there is 2 applications. The first one will install on the server and users will add or delete files using it. The second part will install on the clients and the users will use it to search in the content of files

***UPDATE2** : During all you guys answer my question , I found new feature of SQL Server 2012 named File Table. Can this one help me ?! I think I can use this one and a third party solution to do this ?! Are you agree with me ?!

Comment: Basically, you are talking about a document management system here. What you need depends on your requirements: performance, memory consumption, etc. Can you tell us a bit more about the whole setup? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Try to index all files with Lucene.Net, that will easy for search

Comment: @derape , actually yes, I am creating a Document Management using WPF.I want to do this on LAN. I have a serve app that add and remove files , and the clients want to search in content of files

Comment: I am not sure but can you convert your given string to byte[] then query your database to find those that matches? In that case you won't have load anything back to process

Comment: So you're building a document management system, but don't know how [indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_indexing) works? Can't you try to find third-party solutions that solve this problem?

Comment: @CodeCaster , Can I index the content of files that are stored in SQL database using FileStream ?!

Comment: As CodeCaster stated, I see no reason why not use a third party solution. What you are describing is a very common usecase. You still haven't provided any non-functional requirements to give a proper answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I use new feather of MSSQL 2012 named File Table , and because it support just .doc files, I installed Microsoft IFilter 2.0 to support .docx files. Also create full text index on my file table and it work great

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to go with first solution because, first u can allocate memory to read one file at a time, after it is done, release the memory and allocated the memory to another file and read it. In this process u can return the string u required and no need of big big hard space.